# Web.py daemon communication

Tags: python, web.py

I try to create a web server using web.py in order to talk with a daemon.

The goal is to send commands via HTTP to my web.py (executed in a thread opened by my main daemon); then use a pipe to transmit the commands to my main program.

The final program will have several process and threads, and the web.py interface will be the entry point of the software.

My problem is that web.py instanciate a new class for each request, so I can't find an easy way to pass my pipe to the request handlers. I tried using hooks or processors but it doesn't seems to work.

Have someone succeed to pass an object to the web.py handler ? Or is there a way to store objects somewhere in the web object ?

Comment: I tried to create processor but I can't find a way to inject something to the handler() function. Or my goal is to parse the request, and then send command using a pipe. I thought that maybe with a hook I could create a variable that would be readable inside the handler() function, but it did not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution but it is not crystal clear in the documentation.

I just created a load_hook using web.ctx to store my object :

```
def load_hook():
    web.ctx.pipe = input_p

app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.add_processor(web.loadhook(load_hook))
    app.run()
```

Then I can access web.ctx.pipe in all my classes. Quite simple to do but hard to find in the documentation.

Comment: Also make sure to lock pipe communication, because it is not thread safe.